# Condition after variable binding in guard swift compilation issue

Tags: swift, swift-guard

I am using the nice guard statement from Swift 3.0 (in Xcode 8.0) and have the following function:

```
func parse(suffix s: String) throws -> Instruction {
    guard let count = Int(s) where count >= 0 else {
      throw InstructionParsingError(message: s + " should be a positive integer")
    }
    return CallInstruction(argCount: count)
}
```

My issue is that the swift compiler complains twice about the line containing my guard statement:

```
CallInstruction.swift:42:29: Boolean condition requires 'where' to separate it from variable binding
CallInstruction.swift:42:30: Expected ',' joining parts of a multi-clause condition
```

I tried

- replacing the `where` with a `,` then the second error disappears but the first one is still there.
- replacing the `where` with `, where` but then this line can't even be parsed
- replacing the `count` in the where by `Int(s)` but have the same errors.

How should I change my code so that it compiles? (With a nice single guard statement I mean, of course I could have multiple guards, or ifs or switch but from what I read about the guard statement I should be able to have a clean readable line).

Comment: `guard let count = Int(s), count >= 0 else` should compile with Swift 3/Xcode 8. Perhaps some invisible space or control character in the source code?

Comment: oh ok, I cleaned my product in xcode after the replacement and all errors disappeared. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For solving of this issue i recommend you to use model Swift syntax in guard statement that replace `where` with `,`.

```
func  parse(suffix s: String) {
    guard let count = Int(s), count >= 0 else {
         return
    }
}
```

Also it is possible to use `if let` statement :

```
func  parseTwo(suffix s: String) {
    if let count = Int(s), count >= 0  {
        // done
        print(count)
    } else {
        return
    }
}
```